# why my game is not getting its normal speed back with this code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnMouseDown () {
    if(name == "SlowButton"){
        PlaneMovement.GameSpeed = 0.5f;
    }
    if(name == "MediumButton"){
        PlaneMovement.GameSpeed = 1f;
    }
    if(name == "FastButton"){
        PlaneMovement.GameSpeed = 2f;
    }
    if(name == "VeryFastButton"){
        PlaneMovement.GameSpeed = 3f;
    }
    Application.LoadLevel("game");
    }
```

I enter with this code into the Next Scene and there i have a code for some extra Power like speedup while collision occurs for that the code is:

```
if(C.tag == "Dimond"){
        Camera.main.GetComponent<StoneInitiate>().DimondList.Remove(C.gameObject);
        Destroy (C.gameObject);
        Camera.main.GetComponent<StoneInitiate>().StoneCounter+=20;
        smooth = 4f;
        SpeedUpTimer = 5f;
        SpeedUp = true;
        }
```

speedup code is:

```
PlaneMovement.GameSpeed = Mathf.Lerp (PlaneMovement.GameSpeed,smooth,Time.time);
        if(SpeedUp){
            SpeedUpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            print(SpeedUpTimer);
            if(SpeedUpTimer <= 0){
                SpeedUp = false;
                smooth = PlaneMovement.GameSpeed;
            }
```

It Works Fine when collision occurs but smooth takes value 4f and It Doesn't get value form

```
PlaneMovement.GameSpeed
```

please help me for that I am new in Unity. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Do this and it works..

```
float smooth;
float smooth1;

void Start () {

    smooth = PlaneMovement.GameSpeed;
    smooth1 = PlaneMovement.GameSpeed;
}

PlaneMovement.GameSpeed = Mathf.Lerp (PlaneMovement.GameSpeed,smooth,Time.deltaTime);
    if(SpeedUp){
        SpeedUpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(SpeedUpTimer <= 0){
            SpeedUp = false;
            smooth = smooth1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
PlaneMovement.GameSpeed = Mathf.Lerp (PlaneMovement.GameSpeed,smooth,Time.time);
if(SpeedUp){
  SpeedUpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
  print(SpeedUpTimer);
  if(SpeedUpTimer <= 0){
    SpeedUp = false;
    smooth = PlaneMovement.GameSpeed;
  }
}
```

You are using Lerp incorrectly, the first argument is the From value, the second is the To value and the third is how far you go between From and To, lets call it t.

So for example, say that your From = 1 and To = 2.

If t = 0, then it will return From and thus 1

if t = 1 then it will return To and thus 2

if t = 0.5 then it will return the value half way between 1 and 2 thus 1.5

t is clamped to 0 and 1

You use Time.time which is a number larger then 1 which means that it will always return your smooth. thus GameSpeed will always be equal to smooth after you call

```
PlaneMovement.GameSpeed = Mathf.Lerp (PlaneMovement.GameSpeed,smooth,Time.time);
```

What you want to do is call that line several times with a t of something like 0.5

Lets say GameSpeed is 1 and smooth is 4. When you call this

```
PlaneMovement.GameSpeed = Mathf.Lerp (PlaneMovement.GameSpeed,smooth,0.5f);
```

GameSpeed will now be 2.5. If you call it again with GameSpeed now beeing 2.5 it will become 3,25 and a third time for 3,625. The more you call it the close it will get to 4.

As Rudolfwm pointed out you can make this framerade independant by using the delta time like this

```
PlaneMovement.GameSpeed = Mathf.Lerp (PlaneMovement.GameSpeed,smooth,0.5f * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Its better to Lerp using Time.deltaTime, then a fixed value, since this will make the Lerp framerate independent. To speed up the Lerp multiply Time.deltaTime with a constant of your chosing.

Comment: Yes you are correct but the constant still need to be there so you can tweak how fast it lerps. I have updated the answer.